# Should the controller check !params.nil? for security purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security

I am receiving data for a model from a form_for. The model runs extensive validation of the data, and I am using `if @name.save` to catch any errors.

Does running one of the following before `@name = Name.new(params[:name])`, help keep my website more secure:

```
if !params.nil?
if params.has_key "name"
if params.include? "name"
```

If not for security reasons, is there any other reason to do this? I am not asking about cases when the user input is optional and I want to check if it exists, but about cases when user input is expected, but failed to arrive for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write params.nil? for checking parameters.
Validations should be written in model.
If you are not using rails 4,
you can use 'strong_parameters' gem for allowing only required parameters to model(For security reasons).
strong_parameter gem is already there in rails 4.